# How to choose classifier and classifier parameters during RFS feature selection

Tags: r, svm, feature-selection

I have a matrix 504(r) x 615(c) that has 165 positive, rest negative labels. I am using RFS greedy feature selection (ref: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kdeng/thesis/feature.pdf). I use an SVM with radial kernel for classification during feature selection. I want to know how to choose the SVM’s parameters to get optimum features. This question comes because when I use different parameters (gamma = 0.01 thru 0.7, cost = 0.1, 1, 10, 30) the algorithm comes up with different sets of features.

Update: I took 70% as train set, 30% as cross validation set. I did 2 experiments: 1 with gamma=0.09, cost=10 and the system selected 48 features; 2 with gamma = 0.01, cost=30 and the system selected 39 features. The accuracy on the cross validation set with the first set of features is better than that on the second set.

Comment: Welcome to SO!, to ascertain stability of features you would need cross-validation methods, these might be be helpful , [caret recursive feature elimination](https://topepo.github.io/caret/recursive-feature-elimination.html) and [python sklearn cross validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/model_selection.html)

Comment: Thanks. Also, I did not know about the 'caret' package - thanks for that!

Comment: in general you would need to do nested re-sampling: inner loop for hyper parameter tuning, middle loop for sequential forward selection and outer loop to evaluate performance. Check this [tutorial](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/nested_resampling.html).